# redirect wget header output

Tags: bash, redirect

i'm getting a page with wget in a shell script, but header information going to stdout, how can i redirect it to a file?

```
#!/bin/sh
wget -q --server-response http://192.168.1.130/a.php > /tmp/ilan_detay.out

root@abc ./get.sh
  HTTP/1.0 200 OK
  X-Proxy: 130
  Set-Cookie: language=en; path=/; domain=.abc.com
  X-Generate-Time: 0,040604114532471
  Content-type: text/html
  Connection: close
  Date: Mon, 17 Jan 2011 02:55:11 GMT
root@abc
```

Answer (score 3):

The header info must be going to `stderr` so you'll need to redirect that to a file. To do that change the `>` to `2>`

Answer (score 1):

To get only the server response in a file you can do:

```
wget -q --server-response http://www.stackoverflow.com >& response.txt
```

You can read more about UNIX output redirection [here](http://www.mathinfo.u-picardie.fr/asch/f/MeCS/courseware/users/help/general/unix/redirection.html)